# plus sign in sed

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to do the following:

```
echo "test++abc" | awk -v bar="test++" 'BEGIN {FS=bar} {print $2}'
```

I am expecting to see `abc` as the output, because I used `bar="test++"` as the separator. But I am getting `++abc` instead.

Can anyone please explain this behavior and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "test++abc" | awk -v bar='test[+][+]' 'BEGIN {FS=bar} {print $2}'
```

Comment: `echo "test++abc" | sed 's/test++//g'`

Comment: Option `g` means 'global'. I.e. `echo "test++abctest++" | sed 's/test++//g'` will also return 'abc'. While `echo "test++abctest++" | sed 's/test++//'` will return 'abctest++'.

Comment: `echo "test++abctest++" | sed 's/test+\{2\}//'`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "test++abc" | awk -v bar="test\\+\\+" 'BEGIN {FS=bar} {print $2}'
```

And in sed:

```
echo "test++abc" | sed -e 's/test++//'
```